# How can I use gettimeofday to measure the passage of time?

Tags: c, time, calculation, measure, gettimeofday

I'm only allowed to use this function and I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate time elapsed, any ideas? I'm confused..

```
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/time.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct timeval now;
    struct timeval start;
    int t_now;
    int t_stop;
    int t_start;
    int i;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    t_start = start.tv_usec / 1000;
    t_stop = t_start + 200;

    while (42)
    {
        usleep(2000);
        gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
        t_now = now.tv_usec / 1000;
        if (t_now - t_stop > -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        printf ("%d\n", t_now);
        usleep(2000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was doing this but it will keep looping, and won't stop..

Comment: call it once at the start, remember the tv_sec value, when finished call it again, subtract new tv_sec from old

Comment: @pm100 No this is impossible you can't do this cuz gettimeofday will return you the current time .. I mean in each minute it will counts the minutes back it's not constant wait check this link 
https://blog.habets.se/2010/09/gettimeofday-should-never-be-used-to-measure-time.html

Comment: that blog article is not very good, its confusing and misleading. You asked how to measure elapsed time using gettimeofday, I told you how to do it. What I said will work, if you need more than 1 second accuracy then take into account the tv_usec value too

Comment: Put code in the question, not comments.

Comment: A blog that says not to use `gettimeofday()` is not very helpful if you're *required* to use it. Your assignment doesn't care about the possible problems (which aren't really as significant as he suggests).

Answer (score 0):

this

```
t_start = start.tv_usec / 1000;
```

isnt doing what you expect. tv_usec only has fractions of a second, you need

```
long long msec = (start.tv_sec * 1000) + start.tv_usec/1000;
```

to get total msec

Comment: what is msec? I thought tv_sec and tv_usec are the same value one in microseconds and the other is just seconds..

Comment: @AbrarX nope, secs is the number of seconds, then add usec to get the fractions of second. I show you how to calculate milliseconds, by multiplying seconds by 1000 and adding microseconds / 1000

Comment: okkkaaayyyy I do understand now thank you so much I was confused and I didn't find a website that could explain what sec and usec I thought they are the same ..

Comment: @Abrar use your debugger, i did and i got this `$1 = {tv_sec = 1646094894, tv_usec = 776419}`, its pretty obvious that 776419 is not the time in microseconds!

Comment: oh wait I didn't print them out together .. I misunderstood the manual .. okay I will use the debugger